# Visual Studio Code leave split editor open when empty

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does Visual Studio Code have an option for leaving the split editor screens open when they have no active tabs?

The current behavior is that if I close out of the last open tab in a split screen that the editor removes the split altogether. So if I have the editor split into two vertical screens, it goes back to a single screen once the last file is closed.

Is it possible to make it so that the splits stay active even when empty? This type of behavior is supported in Sublime Text and Atom, but I haven't found an option or any mention of how to do this in VSC.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups` config setting.

Answer (score 9):

It is not supported at the moment but you are not alone in your desire for such a feature.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2755

Comment: Ah nice, thanks for linking that. I'll keep an eye out for updates in the future. Fingers crossed.

Comment: This is no longer true.