# How to keep editor groups fixed even after closing editors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If there are three editor groups opened, each with one editor (file) opened, and I close the editor for one of them, the number of editor groups goes down to two automatically. Is there a way to keep the editor groups fixed (leaving an empty editor group instead of removing it)? Having the number of editor groups is confusing for me, and I know I'll be putting other files in there anyway, so it's inefficient to re-configure the number of editor groups.

Bonus: in Emacs, I can assign an editor group (buffer) into which I want to open a file (when using the `NeoTree` extension I can type `2 ENTER` to open the file in the second buffer (editor group). If I could do the same with VSCode it'd be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code leave split editor open when empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538245/visual-studio-code-leave-split-editor-open-when-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Set](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) `"workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups": false` to disable automatic closing of a group when its last editor is closed